# Android - ListView - lags

Tags: android, listview, scroll, lag

I have a problem with an application on android. More specifically, I have a problem with lagging `ListView`. I use class `ViewHolder`. Actually I do not display a lot of things, but my move Items with large lags.

I do not know what I could change, I tried to found answers in search but found no solution to this problem.

I can scroll my view, but in interval few seconds my view stop for 2 sec. I thought that it is problem with update adapter, but i don't know what can i do change.

Sorry for my English.

Here is the code of the adapter:

```
public class ListAdapter_obiekty extends BaseAdapter{
    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;
    private int screenHeight;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> products,dane;

    ListAdapter_obiekty(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {

        ctx = context;
        this.products = data;
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;

    }

      @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return products == null ? 0 : products.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return products.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public void updateItem(final String name, final String item, final Integer pos) {
        HashMap<String,String> hm = this.products.get(pos);
        hm.put(name, item);
        this.products.set(pos,hm);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;

        HashMap<String, String> hm = this.products.get(position);
        String tryb = hm.get("tryb");

        ListViewHolder holder = null;

        if (view == null) {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
            if (params.height != screenHeight) params.height = screenHeight/2;
            view.setLayoutParams(params);
            holder = new ListViewHolder();
            holder.tryb = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tV_tryb));

            view.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ListViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lista_obiekty_niebieski);
            holder.tryb.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#e3e9e4"));

        }else{
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lista_obiekty_pod_logo);
            holder.tryb.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#007bb3"));
        }


        holder.tryb.setText(hm.get(ctx.getString(R.string.tryb)));

        return view;
    }


    static class ListViewHolder{
        TextView tryb;
    }

}
```

Here is the code to create an adapter and update:

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            adapter = new ListAdapter_obiekty(HomeActivity.this, productsListNAZWY,productsListDANE);
            ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
            for(int i =0; i<=ile; i++){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                HashMap news = null;

                news = (HashMap) productsListNAZWY.get(i);


                String ip = (String) news.get("numer_ip");

                callAsynchronousTask(i, "http://" + ip + "/config/xml.cgi?A|1|74|I|1|29|D|1|62");
                Log.d("TAGS","URUCHOMILEM");


            }

        }
```

And Here is my function callAsynchronousTask() :

```
public void callAsynchronousTask(final int i, final String numerIPx) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {


                    try {

                        obiekt=null;
                        obiekt = new ListaXML();

                        String[] tabAnal = obiekt.execute(numerIPx).get();

                        Integer code = obiekt.code;

                        String trybPracy = "";

                        trybPracy = tabAnal[10];

                        HashMap maps = new HashMap<String,String>();

                        ... more items (5-6)

                        maps.put("trybPracy", trybPracy);

                        adapter.updateItem(maps,i);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 5000);

}
```

Comment: Now I have 2 items displayed and on each item i have 6 item to update, and now my list view has more lags

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the lag is due to this bit of the code

```
    try {
      Thread.sleep(5000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

You're doing this in the main UI thread.

Reduce this time to 100 and see what happens. If it is the cause you will have to re-work your code, as there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your list adapter.

**Edit:** comment out this bit of code to find the lag.

```
 for(int i =0; i<=ile; i++){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            HashMap news = null;

            news = (HashMap) productsListNAZWY.get(i);


            String ip = (String) news.get("numer_ip");

            callAsynchronousTask(i, "http://" + ip + "/config/xml.cgi?A|1|74|I|1|29|D|1|62");
            Log.d("TAGS","URUCHOMILEM");


        }
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answer. I reduce this time to 100, and next i delete this fragment of code. But I still have lags ;/

Comment: but if I comment this fragment i dont have update my adapter.

Comment: This will help you find where the lag is - then you can fix this, as you have 2 5second sleep/delays/

Comment: OK. Thanks u have right, my function update adapter (call asynchronous task) cause me the lags. But I want to update my adapter in interval. Maybe u have the solution to fix that?

Comment: I would suggest you do the cell updating in the getView method.

Comment: @kamilos207 Can you please mark as completed/answered. Thanks!

Comment: Can u explain me what i should do to update my adapter in getView method? Maybe example?

Comment: Can someone tell me what is the best way to update the elements , so that there is no lag ?